# lua: Any difference between returning a local and returning a global variable?

Tags: lua, return, return-type

```
function test1(x) local x=x return x end
function test2(x) return x end
```

Say I'm calling them like test(5). What are the differences behind the scenes on what's going on with the return value here? Any usage of x in the codeblock follows the rules of local, I get that much. But what is happening when I return x? Mainly is the return value different between these two functions or the same? Is either function, when run, handling any more efficiently than the other etc.

My understanding is the return value is spitting out x as a local value to wherever it is called.

```
  function test3()
       test1(5) --local 5
       a=test1(5) --global a=5
    end
```

So is there any difference when this is done with test2(5) instead of test1(5)? Is test1 making x into a local then returning it and test1 simply grabbing the local x that I made local and returning it? Any minor details here?

My interest is mainly for using local as a form of optimization. Like for optimizing collision formula: Whether i should define each argument as local before returning any math done on them.

```
function mult(x,y)
  local x=x
  local y=y
  return x*y
end

function mult2(x,y) return x*y end
```

Comment: Your `x` is a local in both functions, in `test1` you are simply shading the parameter `x` with local `x` and in the cases you have shown it's unnecessary, a book I suggest you read, with examples that will show where `local` matters, [Lua Gems](https://www.lua.org/gems/) some of the optimizations it contains follow your line of questioning, a relevent bit would be the 3rd page in this sample of chapter 2 https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf

Comment: Can you elaborate on a case where it is necessary then...? From what I can tell you are saying the parameters, and therefore the assigned arguments, are always defined as local within the function? So I  would only use local when new variables are assigned within the function? function mult2(x,y) local x=x+33 return x*y end......is this considered different?   function mult2(x,y) local p=x+33 return p*y end is what you are hinting at right? My OP was literally created because I read that doc which outlined locals importance to optimization.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/24729599/… It says explicity if its not declared as local its global. The parameters were not declared as local, so they are global? Or is this a special case that parameters when setup like the examples of function (x) local x=x don't need to be defined as local? Similiar to how for i=1,10 do... the i is automatically local. Or parameters are just placeholders, so they are either local or just something like placeholders, but when variable assignment happens.....the above discussion into play.

Comment: "It says explicity if its not declared as local its global." That's not exactly true. Parameters and the variables in a `for` statement are implicitly local.

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to help, as parameters are not going to be optimized by storing their values in local variables. You may sometimes see this optimization to store table fields (to avoid their associated table access step), but this is not what's going on there.

If you are interested in assigning returned values, then assigning them into local variables will be a tad faster, but I suspect that this is a case of [premature optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization), as it's unlikely that your app will be noticeably helped by this type of changes, unless you're doing this assignment a very large number of times in a loop every second (and even in that case you'd need to profile the app first to confirm that this is what contributes to the problem).